# How to check CPU core usage in Linux or R

Tags: linux, r, unix, cpu-usage

I'm working on a parallel R project for my class. The project is complete, however, I wanted to add a few details on cpu by core usage to show the difference in time and performance between single core and multicore. There's a paper I read which showed the cpu usage as I wanted, but it doesn't have the code or script. It showed the usage like this:

```
﻿1 [                                                 0.0%]   
2 [############################################## 100.0%]    
3 [*                                                0.7%]    
4 [                                                 0.0%]
```

How can show this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: apparently, htop is not installed in our server. I have contacted the administrator, but it's no guarantee that he'll agree to install it. Thank you, though.

Comment: another alternative is `mpstat -P ALL 1`

Comment: Thank you Fredrik. I think I'll use this. It shows cpu usage in more readable format than top in Rstudio shell. I appreciate your help.

Comment: added as an answer, Best way to say thanks is to upvote and/or accept :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/)

or as an alternative, try

```
mpstat -P ALL 1
```

Comment: I should warn people not to do `system("mpstat -P ALL 1")` directly in R Studio, because you'll have to terminate R =D

Answer (score 3):

use top, type 1. Top will show you usage by core.

Comment: I used top, but it doesn't do anything when I type 1. I'm using shell on RStudio. I think that's why. I guess I don't have any other ways to do this then.

Answer (score 2):

On unix and macos you can use top() Funktion of R-Package 'NCMisc':

```
library(NCmisc)
test <- top()
test
$CPU
$CPU$total
[1] 1.4

$CPU$idle
[1] 98.4

$CPU$sys
[1] 0.2

$CPU$unit
[1] "%"


$RAM
$RAM$total
[1] 111.4637

$RAM$used
[1] 34.01906

$RAM$free
[1] 77.44468

$RAM$unit
[1] "Gb"
```